# MySQL Error Log purge / log rotate

Tags: mysql, logging

My MySQL enterprise server has limiting disk space for logging. Error log file increasing size day by day and difficult to limit the size of error log.

Can I Limit MySQL Error Log file size?

Is there any purge command for error log?

Can I apply Log rotation option?

Comment: If your MySQL error log has any significant volume, the problem is related to the errors appearing in the log. Look at resolving those - MySQL error logs even on production systems can go months and only have 1-2k bytes of data in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my Answer,

Scheduled following command weekly basis.

```
mysqladmin -u xxxx -pxxxxxx flush-logs;
```

move old error log file into backup drive.

```
mv /var/lib/xxxxx.err.old /vol3/backup-export
```

Answer (score 1):

It use to be done by operating system.In Debian, for example, *logrotate* do it.

*man logrotate* for more info.

Comment: I does not mentioned about server or apache log. I need to rotate only mysql error log. No issue with mysql bin log.